# Mcrypt with Mamp Pro on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mamp, osx-yosemite

After the Yosemite update yesterday, something is messed up with the Mcrypt extension.
The PHP based [artistan CLI of the Laravel framework](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/artisan) returns:

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

The PATH variable seems to be correct. Where is the misconfig? Before the update everything worked fine.

++++ Configs ++++

Output of 'which php':

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php

'php -v':

> PHP 5.6.1 (cli) (built: Oct 13 2014 18:41:35)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend
>   Technologies

Content of .bash_profile:

> export EDITOR=nano export
>   PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
>   export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin:$PATH

phpinfo():
[image]
[image: Mcrypt part]

MAMP PRO Version:

> 3.0.7.1

**UPDATE:**

Mamp-log says for every extension enabled in php.ini:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: What is the output of `php -m | grep mcrypt`?

Comment: That means the extension isn't enabled or possibly not installed. Check in your `php.ini` for `extension=mcrypt.so`; if it's not in there add that under the dynamic compiled extensions section.

Comment: It is enabled in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini

Comment: If `extension=mcrypt.so` is in the php.ini and it's still not working then you should check that the extension is actually installed, meaning the `mcrypt.so` file. Mine is located in `/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20141012/mcrypt.so`

Comment: Mine is there also. Also getting error in the MAMP log for other extensions. See updated post.

Comment: Did you restart Terminal.app? I know that's obvious, but...

Comment: Yes. Even full system restart

Comment: Another suggestion, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Empty output. I use now  [Maaaark's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26455875/1130036) as temporary workaround.

Comment: seems to be broken again using 3.0.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted MAMP support, and this is what they responded.

> Hi,
>
> Our php.ini file is messed up for 5.6.1. Go to your template files and change this line
>
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1 ....
>
> to
>
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226
>
> We will have a full fix in a few days. You can also just downgrade to php 5.5. in the meantime.

Comment: MAMP has released a new update, 3.0.7.2 which fixes the issues. http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem.

Just use PHP Version 5.5.17 in MAMP and everything should work fine again.

Remember to switch the version in your .bash_profile too:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.17/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me on Yosemite! +1

Answer (score 2):

The hotfix was applied this morning MAMP & MAMP PRO 3.0.7.2 Published: 2014-10-21. 
Default php 5.6.2

Don't forget to update .bash_profile

> export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:$PATH

Everything works fine on my local and it also works fine with drush (for those that use it)

Answer (score 1):

the same error with you, but I perfect sloved it now:

- Stop your MAMP
- Open /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini
- Find all "no-debug-non-zts-20121212" replace by "no-debug-non-zts-20131226"
- Open /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/pear.conf
- Find "no-debug-non-zts-20100525" replace by "no-debug-non-zts-20131226"
- Start your server

I recommend you unistall OS X's default php and apache
Path:

```
/etc/apache2
/usr/include/apahce2
/usr/libexec/apache2
/usr/php
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php-config
/usr/bin/phpize
/usr/include/php
/usr/lib/php
/usr/share/man/man*/php*
/usr/bin/phar.phar
```

then

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/pear /usr/bin/pear
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/peardev /usr/bin/peardev
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/pecl /usr/bin/pecl
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php /usr/bin/php
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First check what php.ini file is loaded:

php --ini

You will probably see that none of the files have been loaded.

2) If you don't mind reinstalling php you can do this:

curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

3) Then set the path to your new php installation in order to avoid using the native php that comes with OSX.

In order to set the path use this command - something like this, bear in mind that your path could be different:

export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH