# Install mcrypt on mac php7.2 MAMP

Tags: terminal, phpmyadmin, mamp, mcrypt

I tried following most of the tutorials here on stack overflow but got no success.

[Issue in installing php7.2-mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt)

https://github.com/tamtamnl/valet-plus/tree/hotfix/homebrew-core-php

https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/issues/127

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26082

[Enable MCrypt using MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504777/enable-mcrypt-using-mamp)

[Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension?rq=1)

---

[Error 1 : Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ICzq.png)

---

[Here's my PHP Version on MAMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVP7h.png)

---

**Here's what I get when I check the version on Terminal**

```html
AVMBP:~ AV$ php -v
PHP 5.6.33 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2018 13:59:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

---

**when I try to install mcrypt on Terminal, here's what I get**

```html
AVsMBP:~ AV$  sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

**I tried the following steps**

```html
brew install mcrypt
```

**here's what I get**

```html
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
youtube-dl

Warning: mcrypt 2.6.8 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.6.8, run `brew reinstall mcrypt`

AVs-Macbook-Pro:~ AV$ brew reinstall mcrypt
==> Reinstalling mcrypt 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mcrypt-2.6.8.yosemite.bottl
Already downloaded: /Users/AV/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mcrypt-2.6.8.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring mcrypt-2.6.8.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.6.8: 18 files, 396.7KB
AVs-Macbook-Pro:~ AV$
```

**then, I check if there's mcrypt installed**

```html
brew search mcrypt
```

**here's what I get**

```html
AVs-Macbook-Pro:~ AV$ brew search mcrypt
==> Searching local taps...

mcrypt ✔                                            libtomcrypt
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
```

After success installing mcrypt through terminal, I added mcrypt.so extension to php.ini.

```html
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini
```

```html
extension=mcrypt.so
```

**I verified if the extension was installed, and I get this ;**

```html
AVs-Macbook-Pro:~ AV$ php -i | grep "mcrypt"
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/php5' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5/php.d' '--with-libxml-dir=shared,/usr' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/php5' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-ldap' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-exif' '--enable-soap' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-ftp' '--with-iodbc' '--enable-sockets' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-zip' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-mhash' '--enable-fpm' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-dtrace' '--enable-opcache' '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-mssql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-imap=shared,../imap-2007f' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr/local/php5' '--with-gettext=/usr/local/php5' '--with-curl=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5' '--with-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-mcrypt=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-tidy=/usr/local/php5' '--with-gmp=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-readline=shared,/usr/local/php5' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php5' 'CC=cc '-L/usr/local/php5/lib' '-I/usr/local/php5/include' '-I/usr/include/libxml2' '-I/usr/local/php5/include/tidy' '-DENTROPY_CH_RELEASE=1'' 'CFLAGS=-Os '-mmacosx-version-min=10.10' '-I/usr/local/php5/include' '-arch' '-no-cpp-precomp' '-DENTROPY_CH_ARCHS='''i386/x86_64'''' '-DENTROPY_CH_RELEASE=1'' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/php5/lib '-arch' 'CXXFLAGS=-arch
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-mcrypt.ini,
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, http.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
AVs-Macbook-Pro:~ AV$
```

**Restarted the system and, I still get this error when I run my php system**

```html
An Error Was Encountered
The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.
```

**Please help me. Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the mcrypt library installed correctly then try below:

https://gist.github.com/idleberg/24479f34dc5007e50d47

Or See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php for other information.

If you are on shared hosting, you can ask your provider to install it.

---

In OSX localhost you can easily install mcrypt via homebrew - as you have tried above:

```
brew install mcrypt
```

Then add this line to your php.ini file.
You can see from the homebrew output above: "/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.6.8"

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.6.8/mcrypt.so"
```

Don't forget to restart server for edits to take effect